# Looking for a regex matching start and end apostrophe only within between string in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've below string I need to be able to dynamicly extract the string Start to End between `apostrophe`:-

"Expected 'TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA' to equal 'TESFSM FDSML F90 TDA'."

The results:

1. TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA
2. ESFSM FDSML F90 TDA

How should the regex look like?

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.findall` with the pattern `'([^']+)'`:

```
inp = "Expected 'TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA' to equal 'TESFSM FDSML F90 TDA'."
matches = re.findall(r"'[^']+'", inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['TESMWQ, WEFSML REDA', 'TESFSM FDSML F90 TDA']
```

Comment: Thank you so much Time Biegeleisen, it works expected :-)